# How to connect to a local SQL Server db from Xamarin VS android app

Tags: android, sql-server, xamarin

I have a working SQL Server database on my laptop, a smart phone linked to the laptop by USB and wi-fi. I have the following code to connect to the database:

```
                string connectionString = @"Data Source=192.168.1.102,1433;Initial Catalog=MyInsurance_database;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=15";
            string databaseTable = "SurveyVariants";
            string whereAnd = "5";
            string selectQuery = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE RecNo = {1}", databaseTable, whereAnd);

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    //open connection
                    connection.Open();

                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);

                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = selectQuery;
                    var result = command.ExecuteReader();
                    //check if account exists
                    var exists = result.HasRows;
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Success - " + exists, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
```

I know that the SQL string is correct and that in SSMS it returns one record correctly.
I have tried various permutations of Server= instead of Data Source=, Initial Catalog= instead of Database=, with and without the port number as 1433, 1434 or 80, after making a new rule for the firewall.
Error messages begin:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Snix_Connect (provider: SNI_PN7, error: 25 - SNI_ERROR_25)
>   Snix_Connect (provider: SNI_PN7, error: 25 - SNI_ERROR_25) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): The socket is not connected
>     at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SSRP.GetPortByInstanceName
>   etc.
>   or
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Snix_Connect (provider: SNI_PN7, error: 40 - SNI_ERROR_40)
>   Snix_Connect (provider: SNI_PN7, error: 40 - SNI_ERROR_40)
>   etc.

What else can I try - any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Is SQL Server installed as the default instance? When you connect through SSMS what name do you select or do you use the IP address?

Comment: When connecting through SSMS I use Server name DD64\SQLEXPRESS where DD64 is the computer name where the database is installed. Authentication is Windows Authentication. Several of the permutations I tried in the connection string included DD64\SQLEXPRESS instead of the IP address.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the default instance? How can I tell from SSMS?

Comment: When you installed SQL Server did you enter a name for your instance or did you accept the defaults during install? From the looks of this you accepted the default instance name.

Comment: `after making a new rule for the firewall` did this every connect properly at one point?

Comment: I'd made a new rule for port 80. although no port specified in the laptop connection string, ie. from desktop VS projects using the databases (9 separate databases for different customers).

Comment: SQL Server connections go through port 1433. Did you open that port on your firewall? Turn off the firewall to test and see if it connects when the firewall is down.

Comment: I turned off the firewall and ran 4 permutations of the connection string. All failed.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Snix_Connect (provider: SNI_PN7, error: 40 - SNI_ERROR_40)
Snix_Connect (provider: SNI_PN7, error: 40 - SNI_ERROR_40)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Have you tested using a SQL User? I am able to connect on Xamarin iOS and Android, but using a SQL User